# Тип enum в typescript?

Tags: typescript

Вопрос прост, может ли кто то привести пример его пользы? Не совсем понимаю какой толк от него. Очень хотелось бы увидеть его в деле.

Ссылка на документацию по нему: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum` удобно использовать для перечисления значений.

Например, в нашем приложении есть сущность `Задача`, которая может быть либо `В работе`, либо `Завершена`.

Мы можем описать её так.

```
interface Task {
  state: State;
}

enum State {
  Running = 'running',
  Finished = 'finished',
}
```

> Сразу оговорюсь, что можно обойтись и без `enum`. Например, используя [String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), [Index Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) или обычные строки. Однако, в этом случае мы либо лишимся некоторых проверок компилятора, либо будем вынуждены дублировать код.

Теперь мы можем работать с состояниями задачи, не боясь указать несуществующее значение или сделать опечатку.

```
let state = State.Running; 

state = State.Finished;
state = 'completed'; // ошибка
```

Часто бывает нужно подобрать пару *каждому* элементу. Например, мы хотим задать текст для отображения в пользовательском интерфейсе.

```
type StateMap = {
    [k in State]: string;
}

const StateLabels: StateMap = {
    [State.Running]: 'В работе',
    [State.Finished]: 'Завершена',
};
```

Если при определении `StateLabels` мы забудем одно из значений или напишем лишнее, компилятор нам об этом подскажет.

Более сложная задача – получить `enum` из произвольной строки. Тут нам помогут [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

```
const stateFromDb = 'finished'; // например, эту строку мы прочитали из базы данных
const stateFromInput = '><script alert(1)'; // а эту – из пользовательского ввода

// Для начала напишем Type Guard – функцию, которая проверяет,
// что строка есть среди значений State
function isValidState(str: string): str is State {
    return Object.keys(State).some(state => {
        return State[state] === str;
    });
}

// Если проверка пройдена – компилятор приведёт строку к State,
// а если нет – возвращаем значение по умолчанию
function toState(str: string) {
    return isValidState(str) ? str : State.Running;
}

toState(stateFromDb); // вернёт State.Finished;
toState(stateFromInput); // вернёт State.Running;
```